# I have a problem with RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#84b56 NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app with a menu tab that shows 3 types of charts, using charts_flutter: ^ 0.8.0, each of the graphs has its own class to generate its values and characteristics, the bar graph works well, the graph of pay works fine, but line chart throws me an error related to size

I tried to add the LineChart in a sizedbox and in a container but it doesn't work or maybe I'm doing it wrong

```
[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RangeError was thrown during performLayout():[39;49m
RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 7

[38;5;244mUser-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mLineChart[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      RangeError.checkValidRange  (dart:core/errors.dart:333:9)[39;49m
[38;5;244m#1      List.sublist  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:81:22)[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      LineRenderer._createAreaSegment[39;49m
[38;5;248m#3      LineRenderer._createLineAndAreaSegmentsForSeries[39;49m
[38;5;248m#4      LineRenderer._createLineAndAreaElements[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#e88cb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
[38;5;244mRenderObject: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#e88cb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
    [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=344.0, h=420.0)[39;49m
    [38;5;244msemantic boundary[39;49m
    [38;5;244msize: MISSING[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#e88cb NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mUser-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mLineChart[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#4f055 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
[38;5;244mRenderObject: RenderPointerListener#4f055 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
    [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
    [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=344.0, h=420.0)[39;49m
    [38;5;244msize: MISSING[39;49m
    [38;5;244mbehavior: deferToChild[39;49m
    [38;5;244mlisteners: down[39;49m
    [38;5;244mchild: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#e88cb NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE[39;49m
        [38;5;244mparentData: <none> (can use size)[39;49m
        [38;5;244mconstraints: BoxConstraints(w=344.0, h=420.0)[39;49m
        [38;5;244msemantic boundary[39;49m
        [38;5;244msize: MISSING[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#4f055 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mUser-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mLineChart[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#379af NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mUser-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mLineChart[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════[39;49m
RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject<num>#e88cb
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[38;5;244mUser-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mLineChart[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The class of the line graph is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() => runApp(LineChart());

class LineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyHomePage();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<charts.Series<Sales, int>> _seriesLineData;

    _generarData(){

    var linesalesdata = [
      Sales(0, 45),
      Sales(1, 56),
      Sales(2, 55),
      Sales(3, 60),
      Sales(4, 61),
      Sales(5, 70),
    ];

    var linesalesdata1 = [
      Sales(0, 35),
      Sales(1, 46),
      Sales(2, 45),
      Sales(3, 50),
      Sales(4, 51),
      Sales(5, 60),
    ];

    var linesalesdata2 = [
      Sales(0, 20),
      Sales(1, 24),
      Sales(2, 25),
      Sales(3, 40),
      Sales(4, 45),
      Sales(5, 60),
      Sales(5, 60),
    ];

    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff990099)),
        id: 'Air Pollution',
        data: linesalesdata,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff109618)),
        id: 'Air Pollution',
        data: linesalesdata1,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xffff9900)),
        id: 'Air Pollution',
        data: linesalesdata2,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Sales, int>>();
    _generarData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Ventas en los ultimos 5 años',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              Expanded(
                child: charts.LineChart(
                  _seriesLineData,
                  defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                  animate: true,
                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                  behaviors: [
                    charts.ChartTitle('Años',
                    behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                    titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                    charts.ChartTitle('Ventas',
                    behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
                    titleOutsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                    charts.ChartTitle('Departamentos',
                    behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.end,
                    titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea)
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Sales {
  int yearval;
  int salesval;

  Sales(this.yearval, this.salesval);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: lost MaterialApp 
step 2: linesalesdata2 have duplicate Sales(5, 60) 
step 3: duplicate id Air Pollution change to 1 or 2, if you use the same id, when click line, only one point will show the other two point won't show 
step 4: Wrap padding with Container

full code without error message

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() => runApp(LineChart());

class LineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<charts.Series<Sales, int>> _seriesLineData;

  _generarData(){

    var linesalesdata = [
      Sales(0, 45),
      Sales(1, 56),
      Sales(2, 55),
      Sales(3, 60),
      Sales(4, 61),
      Sales(5, 70),
    ];

    var linesalesdata1 = [
      Sales(0, 35),
      Sales(1, 46),
      Sales(2, 45),
      Sales(3, 50),
      Sales(4, 51),
      Sales(5, 60),
    ];

    var linesalesdata2 = [
      Sales(0, 20),
      Sales(1, 24),
      Sales(2, 25),
      Sales(3, 40),
      Sales(4, 45),
      Sales(5, 60),
      //Sales(5, 60),
    ];

    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff990099)),
        id: 'Air Pollution',
        data: linesalesdata,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff109618)),
        id: 'Air Pollution1',
        data: linesalesdata1,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xffff9900)),
        id: 'Air Pollution2',
        data: linesalesdata2,
        domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.yearval,
        measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.salesval,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Sales, int>>();
    _generarData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Ventas en los ultimos 5 años',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                Expanded(
                  child: charts.LineChart(
                      _seriesLineData,
                      defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                      animate: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                      behaviors: [
                        charts.ChartTitle('Años',
                            behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                            titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                        charts.ChartTitle('Ventas',
                            behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
                            titleOutsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                        charts.ChartTitle('Departamentos',
                            behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.end,
                            titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea)
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Sales {
  int yearval;
  int salesval;

  Sales(this.yearval, this.salesval);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at your var `linesalesdata2`. It has `Sales(5, 60),` repeated twice. Just correct last item to `Sales(6, 60)` and it should fix your issue.